# How to open .sqlite-wal

Tags: macos, sqlite

I want to export my shazamed tags from the mac app. The app does not offer any export options.
Shazam for Mac is storing them in a sqlite 3 database.

The app is generating 3 files:

- `ShazamDataModel.sqlite`
- `ShazamDataModel.sqlite-shm`
- `ShazamDataModel.sqlite-wal`

The data is stored in `ShazamDataModel.sqlite-wal`.

I cannot open this file with an sqlite browser only with a text editor of course.
How can I export it for example to csv?

Comment: If the database is properly closed, then a `.sqlite-wal` file shouldn't exist. In any case, it isn't intended to be readable by itself; SQLite uses it to implement atomic commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite uses multiple files to store the data of a single database, but you do not need to concern yourself with this.

The name of the actual database file is `ShazamDataModel.sqlite`; just open this one.

Comment: it is empty and its size is small however -wal is much bigger. it is asking for a key

Comment: @iosMentalist If the file is encrypted, you need the correct key. Anyway, to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @iosMentalist Use `sqlite3` command in terminal to read a `.sqlite` database that is split into WAL (Write-Ahead Logging) & -shm (shared memory) files.

Answer (score 0):

There will be three files 
1) .db
2) .db-shm
3) .db-wal

open .db file with any SQLite Browser and it will populate the databases.